# Android - SQlite - Store null into a double field?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, double

I am storing a double into a sqlite database.
This value can be null, and I need to know whether the value is 0 or null.

Is it possible to achieve this?

```
//grade is a type double in database
Double myValue =  cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("grade"));
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To check for null use 'isNull(...)'...

```
Double myValue;
if (!cursor.isNull(cursor.getColumnIndex("grade"))
    myValue =  cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("grade"));
else
    // Handle null scenario
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store it as a string and parse it on the way in and out.